# Выход из приложения не работает

Tags: java, android

Здравствуйте.

В приложении есть меню, туда я добавил кнопку выход.

Не выходит реализовать выход из приложение.

Метод который определяет какая кнопка в меню была нажата:

```
if (id == R.id.exit) {
    super.onDestroy(); //это почему-то не срабатывает, хотя я сомневаюсь что это должно сработать
}
```

Comment: методы жизненного цикла вызывать вручную нельзя. Используйте this.finish();

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте найти кнопку выхода из приложения в каком нибуть приложении от гугл типа Drive или Gmail, или просто в крупном приложении типа клиент Vk или Facebook. Не найдете.

А знаете почему? Потому что андроид приложения не расчитаны на то чтоб из них выходили, это вам не виндовс. Приложения просто сворачиваются, а дальше система сама его закроет, если будет необходимость и оно станет ненужным.

Comment: Ну это распространенное заблуждение, что кнопка выход типа в Android не нужна. Это конечно же не так. А как же быть в случае, если речь идет о приложении для работы с банковскими счетами, хранением паролей и проч? Выход конечно же нужен. Кстати, в том же Facebook/Skype такие кнопки есть :) Просто не надо путать выход с уничтожением/kill приложения. Надо на выходе убирать связанные с логином хэндлеры и токены.

Comment: @Barmaley я писал про "выход из приложения", а вы про logout.

Comment: я про кнопку **выход** что там под ни имелось бы ввиду

Comment: @Barmaley Я хотел донести до автора что делать `System.exit(0);` или `killProcess()` это ненормально.

Comment: А я хотел донести до вас мысль, что выход из приложения это нормально - в общем мы поняли друг-друга :)

Comment: @anber а почему это `System.exit(0)` ненормально? Если из активити была запущена активити (и так несколько раз), и внезапно потребовалось завершить все, то `System.exit(0)` будет лучше, чем много раз вызывать `finish()`

Comment: @SuperCreeper http://stackoverflow.com/a/16480930/1159507

Comment: @SuperCreeper есть разница между graceful exit и прибиванием молотком, чаще всего - в отрабатывании событий закрытия.

Comment: @Barmaley♦, при всем уважении, Вы не правы. Необходимость в кнопке "Exit", говорит о плохом дизайне приложения. А вот "Sign Out/Log Off", совсем другое дело, они как раз и присутствуют там где Вы описали. То что их часто перводят на русский как "Выход", не делают их по сути способом выхода из приложения. Так что @anber прав.

Comment: *Выход* в моем понимании и есть *sign out/logout*. Прибивание приложения есть *Завершение* - не находите? Да и не надо быть таким категоричным - есть немало "плохо" спроектированных приложений, которые скачиваются миллионами копий и в то же время миллионы "хорошо" спроектированных лежащих на полке. Теперь посмотрите внутрь себя и спросите что такое хорошо и что такое плохо :)

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение

```
if (id == R.id.exit) {
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Comment: плохое решение.

Comment: это решение аналогично тому что вы выдерните вилку из розетки выключая ПК. правильнее нажать на кнопку и подождать пока ПК сам выключится.  

оnDestroy(); - это не метод. это событие, которое происходит при "разрушении" сущности (активити или сервиса). т.е. это уже результат то что приложение выключается.

Вам нужно остановить всю активность своего приложения (таймеры, подписчики и прочее) затем вызвать метод finish(). Ориентировочно после этого приложение само закроется.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и кувалдой:

```
 android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

А можно завести свой корневой активити, от которого наследовать все свои, тогда сработает такой кодик:

```
public class MyRootActivity extends Activity
{
    private static ArrayList<Activity> activities=new ArrayList<Activity>();


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        activities.add(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        activities.remove(this);
    }

    public static void finishAll()
    {
        for(Activity activity:activities)
           activity.finish();
    }
}
```

Тогда достаточно будет вызвать в любом месте: `MyRootActivity.finishAll()`

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое решение:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
```

---

В `Oncreate()` `FirstActivity`

```
if (getIntent().getBooleanExtra("EXIT", false)) {
 finish();
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю зачем вызывать новый класс активити, чтоб в onCreate завершить работу с ним?

Comment: @ConstantinePl запуская активити с флагом FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP, мы оставляем в Task'e только корневое ативити, завершаем его, тем самым выходим из приложения.

Answer (score 0):

Можно вызвать у всех активити лежащих в бэкстеке finish(). Это можно сделать при помощи BroadcastReceiver. Минус этого решения состоит в том что каждая активити будет содержать ресивер, что может повлечь за собой потерю лишних ресурсов. (https://stackoverflow.com/a/9413702)